# Why I cannot add more than Five filter option to opencart

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have added 4 filters grops i.e Color, Price, Size and Storage with more than 12 option under this 4 filter.

But When I create category and goto `-> Data -> filter`  I try to add filters I am able to only 5 default option only. When I type Price not all filters under prices are displayed in drop down list instead no drop is there when I type. See I have written pri but only default options are sold and not all realting to price.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: maybe there is a limit set for this. did you checked?

Comment: how to check that
can u guide me with the process

Comment: How to check and edit the filter limit in opencart @AliZia

Comment: I couldn't find the file admin/catalog/filter/autocomplete.@AliZia

Answer (score 2):

Go to `admin/catalog/filter/autocomplete`. Autocomplete is the function name.

Check Line 410.

Change

```
$filter_data = array(
            'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
            'start'       => 0,
            'limit'       => 5
        );
```

to

```
$filter_data = array(
            'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
            'start'       => 0,
            'limit'       => 20
        );
```

Comment: I couldn't find catlog folder under under admin 
i could reach the file path u said. I am using Cpanel File Manager to reach the path @Ali

Comment: don't you have filezilla? where is your site located of opencart?

Comment: not I am using file manager of Cpanel. I could find admin, Catlog, System folders and few other files there. Can you tell me exact path @Ali zia

Comment: there are four folders inside admin folder that are: COntroller; Language; Model and View and few files...

Comment: yes I got it 
the correct address was : admin>controller>catlog>filter.php
I made the change u said and it works

Comment: I hv done but my reputation is still 5
thats y not acepting

Answer (score 0):

although this is an old post, it is easy to say: 
this is a search box, just type the keyword and the list will be updated.

no code change is required.